# Woocommerce theme development php error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I have started developing a theme for woocommerce just now. I have my woocommerce plugin installed and I've just typed in my front-page.php the woo_head hook `woo_head()` but when I execute it I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function woo_head() in /usr/home/danielvivancos.com/web/edu/wordpress/wp-content/themes/codepeople-light-child/header.php on line 29

The same happens with `woo_main_before()` and `woo_loop_before()`... and so on.
How can I get support to use these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly that, *the function does not exist*.

You are probably using a Woo Theme as reference. Open the file `functions.php` and go copying the functions you need to your own file. It's better to do this one by one, so you'll get to know what each does.